# "Cant subset columns" error in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using R markdown for my capstone project and when I try to run this code chunk:

```
data_1_year_v2 <- data_1_year_v2[!(data_1_year_v2$ride_length <= 0)]
```

I get this error:

```
Error in data_1_year_v2[!(data_1_year_v2$ride_length <= 0)]:
! Cannot subset columns with !(data_1_year_v2$ride_length <= 0).
✖ Logical subscript !(data_1_year_v2$ride_length <= 0) must be size 1 or 12, not 5719877.
Backtrace:
 1. data_1_year_v2[!(data_1_year_v2$ride_length <= 0)]
 7. vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
 8. vctrs:::stop_indicator_size(...)
```

If anyone could provide help I would appreciate it :)

Comment: You’re just missing a comma

Answer (score 0):

When subsetting like this, I suggest pulling out your criteria as it's own variable so you can examine it on it's own.

```r
criteria <- !(data_1_year_v2$ride_length <= 0)

data_1_year_v2[criteria,]
```

Also, you're probably missing the comma after the row criteria.

Comment: Also i typed in this code in a different chunk : data_1_year_v2 %>%
  group_by(member_casual) %>%
  count(member_casual) and get a object not found error

Comment: @EnriqueH `count` does the grouping for you.  You don't need to `group_by` first

Comment: i tried that and still got the same error :/